# Jenkins Pipelines with Gradle release plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I'm using Jenkins Pipelines to build my packages and deliver them to Artifactory. I'm trying to use it with Gradle, through the [Gradle Release Plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release), but there's something wrong with it.

I'm starting a ssh-agent so that Gradle has the permission to push on Git repository:

```
sshagent([git_credential]) {
    sh "./gradlew clean release unSnapshotVersion -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true -Prelease.releaseVersion=${release_version} -Prelease.newVersion=${development_version}"
}
```

The problem is Gradle seems to run asynchronously, the ssh-agent stops before the end of Gradle execution. See the Jenkins log above:

```
[Pipeline] sshagent
[ssh-agent] Using credentials git
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Java/JNR ssh-agent
[ssh-agent] Registered BouncyCastle on the remote agent
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Release - MyModule] Running shell script
+ ./gradlew clean release unSnapshotVersion -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true -Prelease.releaseVersion=1.1.0 -Prelease.newVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
:clean
:release
:Release - MyModule:createScmAdapter
:Release - MyModule:initScmAdapter
:Release - MyModule:checkCommitNeeded
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
:Release - MyModule:checkUpdateNeeded
Running [git, remote, update] produced an error: [fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address
error: Impossible de récupérer origin]
:Release - MyModule:checkUpdateNeeded FAILED
:release FAILED
Release process failed, reverting back any changes made by Release Plugin.
```

Is it possible to force Gradle to run synchronously?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs misleaded me, ssh-agent was exiting because Gradle had no access to GIT repository. In fact, in was cloning a Bitbucket repo using https, which needs user+pwd.
When cloning the same repo using SSH, the ssh-agent provides the certificates and Gradle is able to communicate with Bitbucket.